# How to render a different layout for login action with Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, action, render

I am a bit confused where to find login action and how to render for it a different layout.

In `routes.rb` is following statement:

```
  devise_for :users, path_names: { sign_in: "login", sign_out: "logout" },
                     controllers: { omniauth_callbacks: "authentications", registrations: "users/registrations" }
```

When I load `/users/login`, I get the page where I can log in.

I've tried to add `login` action to `/controllers/users/registrations_controllers.rb`, but it didn't work out.

I'll be grateful for every advice.
Thank you

Comment: Are you trying to modify the view or override the sign_in action?

Comment: I want to only modify view, but I would rather define the layout that I want to load in controller than to solve it with "IFs" in the view.

Comment: You should be looking at `SessionsController` and not `RegistrationController` if you want to customize `login/logout`.  Devise has lots of good wiki docs, you can get started here: http://devise.plataformatec.com.br/#getting-started/configuring-controllers

Answer (score 0):

you can just override the devise controller not the action in that and just set `layout 'your layout'` in that controller

Answer (score 0):

You can override devise's default templates by creating the following templates:

```
app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb (or haml or slim...)
app/views/layouts/devise.html.erb (or haml or slim...)
```